# Unable to post files using ajax post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

We use ASP.Net Mvc 4.0.

My objecctive is to save a form with both normal input fields as well as file input fields.
I should be able to add extra data while posting.
I should be able to do perform few actions on 'Ajax Post's Success.

We used ajax post to post the form data as we could accomplish above 2, but failed in serializing and posting of files to server.

Whenever we post using ajax post, always Request.Files.Count == 0, when i check in my controller's Post Action.

ajax post i have used is:

```
        function PostData(formId, eventSource, eventName, eventArgs, controlId) {
   var $dialogForm = $("#" + formId + "Form");

   fdata = $dialogForm.serialize();
   fdata = fdata + '&eventSource=' + eventSource + "&eventName=" + eventName + '&eventArgs=' + eventArgs;

    $.ajax({
        url: $dialogForm.attr("action"),
        type: $dialogForm.attr("method"),
        cache: false,
        data: fdata,
        success: function (result) {
            ProcessEvent(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Please provide me a solution for this!

Comment: Please add your ajax code and controller code you tried!

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-ajax-file-upload/

Answer (score 0):

well you cannot upload files when you go with the concept of ajax. But there are tweaks which are used to upload file and form data using ajax. Whenever a file type is encountered in a form the form data along with file can be copied to an iframe and the iframe can be submitted which give you a feel that file has been uploaded along with other form data  using ajax.

There are various plugin available in jquery which ease this task for you.
One of my favourite is ajax form

```
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload
```

You can use this one..

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for the suggestion, but i have to implement without frames!

Comment: its not frames..its iframes and those are internals..you need to use plugin only to make it work..once the work is done iframe is deleted by the plugin..technically there is no other way you can acheive file upload with ajax without iframe..if I am wrong anyone correct me..thanks..

Comment: Sorry, actually i meant iframes!